# ClassCastException: FrameLayout to RelativeLayout.Params

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I write a method to set an image within a relative layout with this code:

```
private void setHitImageOnShip (Ship ship, View view) {
            ImageView hitImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutSetupActivity);
            //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, view.getId());
            hitImage.setLayoutParams(params);
            hitImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_hit);
            layout.addView(hitImage);
        }
```

Why do I get the below mentioned exception by casting? I did not expect to have a FrameLayout anywhere:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
            at org.nse.battleship.SetupPlayerFieldActivity$MyDragListener.setHitImageOnShip(SetupPlayerFieldActivity.java:319)
```

To be absolutely precisely, I do not want a FrameLayout and have no idea where it comes from! Within my layout-xml there is not FrameLayout at all, see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/layoutSetupActivity"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@drawable/background_blue"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageSetzeSchiffe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:src="@drawable/image_schiffe_setzen"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:src="@drawable/image_playfield"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageSetzeSchiffe"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <!--<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonDrehen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_drehen"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>-->
       <!-- <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_a1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_a1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-276dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonDrehen"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageShipBig"/>-->
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonSpielen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_spielen"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageShipSpeedboat"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageShipCarrier"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageShipCarrier"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageShipCarrier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image_ship_carrier"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageShipCruiser"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageSetzeSchiffe"/>
        <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonDrehen"/>-->
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageShipCruiser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image_ship_cruiser"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagePlayfield"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageShipGunboat"
                android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageShipGunboat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image_ship_gunboat"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageShipCruiser" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonSpielen"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonSpielen"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageShipSubmarine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image_ship_submarine"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonSpielen" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonSpielen"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonSpielen"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageShipSpeedboat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/image_ship_speedboat"
                android:contentDescription="@string/startscreen"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageShipCruiser"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageShipCruiser"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageShipCruiser"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you just cast the `params` to a FrameLayout.LayoutParams?

Comment: I do not expect a framelayout I use RelativeLayout.

Comment: RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutSetupActivity); change id in the xml and check...

Comment: please show your layout code.

Comment: I added the code, please have a look @AnandSingh and thank you for your time.

Comment: For those who down voted me: Why? This is a serious problem.

Comment: So you have the above layout set as content view via setContentView in activity?

Comment: I have set the whole xml file where the whole layout sits (= file name) as content view that is: setContentView(R.layout.setupplayerfield);

Comment: So, as pointed in comments below, .getLayoutParams are associated with parent container. I haven't read android documentation, but are you sure that it is relative layout? According to me it would be better to make some "Layout Wrapper" which could be used as setContentView. Then you can add your current layout in this wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

`layout.getLayoutParams()` returns the type of layout parent. So your relative layout is probably inside frame layout and that's why it throws an exception.

In your case, remove

```
RelativeLayout layout = RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutSetupActivity);
```

and use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout)hitImage.getLayoutParams()
```

Comment: That is not the case. There is no FrameLayout at all in my layout.

Comment: I think basic android container is Framelayout. Either way, if you use hitImage.getLayoutParams() it will work

Comment: So you recommend getting the layout parameters from the hitImage?

Comment: The hitImage is being loaded later on, so why does it have any layoutParams? Your solution states another Exception: "Cannot cast from LayoutParams to RelativeLayout" @vandzi

Comment: Every view has some layout params. Layout params help to layout(relative, linear, frame) to find correct position for every view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **LayoutParams** of the **ViewGroup** the **ImageView** is sitting in. So your code should like

```
layout.addView(hitImage, params);
```

I think you are trying to put the **ImageView** at the center of your **RelativeLayout**.

Comment: I would like to set the hitView at the center of the view being given in as parameter of the method.

Comment: My code snipet is doing exactly that thing. Here hitImage will be added at the center of layout.

Comment: But the code did not reach the layout.addView(....) so far. It stopped before in the line: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout)hitImage.getLayoutParams();

Answer (score 0):

The error was in creating/getting those layoutParams wrong.

I removed

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
```

and used

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

instead.
As it seems the hitImage is right of the other imageView and not as intended in the center. What is wrong?